# file upload error, "not found on selected data source"

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I've written the following code and when it was simply uploading the file to the folder everything was fine. I've changed it to insert the file name and file path into a database and I'm getting an error:

*A field or property with the name 'DataUpload' was not found on the selected data source*

DataUpload is the folder name and worked fine before. I'm probably missing something simple but I'm not seeing it.

```
protected void ButtonSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    try
    {

        FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("DataUpload\\" + FileUpload1.FileName));
        Guid newGUID = Guid.NewGuid();

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        conn.Open();

        string FileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
        string InsertUser = "INSERT INTO UserUpload (ID, Comment, FilePath, FileName) VALUES (@ID, @Comment, @FilePath, @FileName)";

        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(InsertUser, conn);

        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", newGUID.ToString());
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Comment", TextBoxComment.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FilePath", "DataUpload/" + FileName);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileName", FileName);

        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        LabelMessage.Text = ("Your Upload Is Complete");


        conn.Close();


    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        LabelMessage.Text = ("Error:" + ex.Message);

    }
}
```

Comment: Try to give your folder path like this

"~/ContentFolder/anyfolder/Filename

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Add single quotes to the string you are creating for the FilePath, like:`string.Format("'DataUpload/{0}'", FileName);`

Comment: I tried that and also commented out everything but the one upload line and it still doesn't work. The page refuses to load. I think there is some other underlying issue. I even deleted the old DataUpload folder and changed everything to Data_Upload, the paged loaded with the old DataUpload error.

Comment: I found the problem. The code was fine, the gridview on the page had the old schema. Refreshed it and the code I originally posted works.